# Can Someone explain this code on the creation of a radar chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble understanding this piece of code from another question, I believe it is due to my inexperience using matplotlib, could someone please outline what the key features do etc. I have asked my computer science teacher who wasn't able to help. For example, I really don't understand what the use of the splicing does for the program and the general formation of data.

```
N = len(positionAttributes)
x_as = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]

# Because our chart will be circular we need to append a copy of the first 
# value of each list at the end of each list with data
values += values[:1]
x_as += x_as[:1]
# Set color of axes
plt.rc('axes', linewidth=0.5, edgecolor="#888888")
# Create polar plot
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

# Set clockwise rotation. That is:
ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

# Set position of y-labels
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
# Set color and linestyle of grid
ax.xaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.1)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.1)

# Set number of radial axes and remove labels
plt.xticks(x_as[:-1], [])
# Set yticks
plt.yticks([20, 40, 60, 80, 100], ["20", "40", "60", "80", "100"])

# Plot data
ax.plot(x_as, values, linewidth=2, linestyle='solid', zorder=3)

# Fill area
ax.fill(x_as, values, 'royalblue', alpha=0.09)

# Set axes limits
plt.ylim(0, 100)


# Draw ytick labels to make sure they fit properly
for i in range(N):
    angle_rad = i / float(N) * 2 * pi

    if angle_rad == 0:
        ha, distance_ax = "center", 10
    elif 0 < angle_rad < pi:
        ha, distance_ax = "left", 1
    elif angle_rad == pi:
        ha, distance_ax = "center", 1
    else:
        ha, distance_ax = "right", 1

    ax.text(angle_rad, 100 + distance_ax, positionAttributes[i], size=7, horizontalalignment=ha, verticalalignment="center")
```

Comment: Please limit your post to a specific issue you are having. As is, this is too broad of a question for the site.

Comment: If by "splicing" you mean the `[:1]`, that is used to add the first value again at the end of the data for let the data revolve completely around the circle. Note that `values += values[:1]` is equivalent to `values += values[0]` which might be easier to understand.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Why doe the code x_as = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)] times by 2 and then pi, i get it needs to find the data to organise the x axis, but what does this bit do

Comment: This gets you `N` equally distributed points on a circle. Possibly this line should be written as `x_as = numpy.linspace(0, 2*nump.pi, N+1)` and then the line `x_as += x_as[:1]` being removed.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thankyou thats really helpfull, also what do the calculations do throughout the code, plt.xticks(x_as[:-1], []) is particularly confusing to me. Thanks in advance